# Is it possible to perform a visual block selection programmatically using line and column numbers?

Tags: vimscript, visual-block

I've looked around in `:help V` but haven't found anything of this sort, but was wondering if there's a function I can call from vimscript that would visually select a region based on (row, column) coordinate pairs.

For example, I could call it with `(1,1),(2,3)` to visually select the rectangle with the top left corner at row 1, column 1, and bottom right corner at row 2, column 3.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: You first need to set the visual type manually using e.g. `exe "norm! \<c-v>\<esc>"` for visual block mode. Then you can set the marks `'<`, `'>` manually using `setpos()`. Then use `gv`

Comment: Following @ChristianBrabandt idea you could write it [like this](https://gist.github.com/statox/5b79f7e72ca650ed0a26ae1bdfea35eb) it seems to be working very well!

Comment: @statox, I am using this technique for my [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn/blob/master/autoload/nrrwrgn.vim#L1312-L1315) plugin.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt So that's an already tested code, great :) You could write an answer, I think it matches pretty well OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this similarly to how you would do it manually, by using the [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) command:

```
:normal! 1G1|^V2G3|
```

The `^V` is a CTRL-V character. You can enter this literally by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, but as you’re most likely going to need to build the command as a string anyway so you can use variables for the line/column numbers, using a [string escape sequence](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string) is cleaner:

```
:execute "normal! 1G1|\<C-V>2G3|"
```

In an actual script, I'd probably break it up over a few lines to make it a bit clearer what you're doing:

```
let select_command = line1 . 'G' . column1 . '|'
let select_command .= "\<C-V>"
let select_command .= line2 . 'G' . column2 . '|'
execute 'normal!' select_command
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct function available to create a new block-wise selection. However you can work around it the following way:

1) First you need to set the visual selection type, so that when using `gv` the selection will be set correctly. You can simply abort it right afterwards, so e.g. use `:exe ":norm! \<c-v>\<esc>`. This sets block-wise selection and aborts it right afterwards.

2) Since patch [7.3.590](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/0306ac33a53114113825242d2) the visual marks `'<` and `'>` that define the start and end position of the visual selection are directly settable using `setpos()`.

3) After the marks have been set, you can then use `gv` to "reselect" the last visual selected area. I have been using this technique in my [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin ever since that patch has been included ([commit](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn/commit/4911ef6438e3ab26051b4635362)) and is has been working well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Rich

```
function MyVertBlock(line1, line2, column1, column2)
let select_command = a:line1 . 'G' . a:column1 . '|'
let select_command .= "\<C-V>"
let select_command .= a:line2 . 'G' . a:column2 . '|'
execute 'normal!' select_command
endfunction
```

```
call MyVertBlock(1, 10, 2, 4)
```